# Encabezados en las preflight request en Angular y Spring boot

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http, cors

Me preguntaba si se puede agregar encabezados en las preflight request que realiza Angular a los MS de Spring boot y es que e realizado las configuraciones correspondientes en el HttpRequestInterceptor de angular utilizando la siguiente configuración:

```
requestClone = req.clone({
    withCredentials: environment.production,
    setHeaders: {
      Pragma: "no-cache",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "cookie-prueba": cookie-prueba,
     "Strict-Transport-Security":"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    },
    url: `${environment.host}${req.url}`,
  });
  return next.handle(requestClone);
```

Adicionalmente configure el YML del gateway del backend para configurar CORS

```
cors:
  allowedMethods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
  allowedOrigins: *
  enabled: true
  mapping: /*
  allowedHeaders: '*'
```

Sin embargo, solo las peticiones GET, POST, PUT y DELETE llegan con encabezado y la petición OPTIONS llega sin dicha información.

Agregando otras configuraciones extras, modifique el archivo de nginx.conf de Angular:

```
location / {        
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";        
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";        
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;      
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";        
    add_header 'Strict-Transport-Security' 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains' always;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";        
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
```

y en cada endpoint agregue la anotación `@CrossOrigin` para verificar se hacían alguna diferencia en los encabezados de las peticiones OPTIONS, pero no obtuve los resultados esperados

**Actualización**

Agregue un filtro del lado del backend para asignar los encabezados de las respuestas y de la misma forma no se integran en las preflight request, pero si las demás peticiones

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class HeaderController {
    @ModelAttribute
    public void corsHeaders(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains");
    }
}
```